# Prove that, for a closed subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$, $(W^{\perp})^{\perp} = W$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

Prove that, for a closed subspace $W$ of a (infinite dimensional) vector space $V$, (with inner product) $(W^{\perp})^{\perp} = W$.

The notion 'closed' is in relation to the natural metric $d (x,y) = \|x-y\|$ with $\|\cdot\|$ defined as $\sqrt{\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle}$

This is a basic fact that I have found referenced but not proven. I know that, for all subspaces $U$, $U^{\perp}$ is closed.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by closed subspace?

Comment: @aboat Presumably this is a topological vector space, in which case it means topologically closed.  The OP should be more precise about the nature of the ambient space, e.g. whether it's a Banach space or more general.

Comment: Thanks-edited to be more precise (has inner product)

Comment: See also: [A subspace $X$ is closed iff $X =( X^\perp)^\perp$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051514)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show that for any subspace $W$, $W^{\perp\perp} = W^-$. (Closure)

Observe that
$$ W^{\perp\perp} = \{v \in V\mid \forall w \in W^\perp, \langle v, w \rangle = 0\} = \{v \in V\mid \forall w \in V, (\forall u \in W, \langle u,w \rangle = 0 \implies \langle w,v \rangle = 0)\}
$$
Then $u \parallel v$, so that $W \subseteq W^{\perp\perp}$. Since any orthogonal complement is closed, $W^{\perp\perp}$ is closed. Since $W^-$ is the smallest closed set containing $W$, we have $W^- \subseteq W^{\perp\perp}$.

Conversely, let $w \in W^{\perp\perp}$. Assume that $w \not\in W^-$. By the Hilbert Projection Theorem, ($W^-$ is convex) there exists $ w_0 \in W^-$ and some $w_1\mid w_1\neq 0, w_1 \perp W^-$ such that $w = w_0 + w_1$. Thus,
$$ \langle w, w_1 \rangle = \langle w_0 + w_1, w_1 \rangle = \langle w_1, w_1 \rangle > 0
$$
hence $w \not\in W^{\perp\perp}$. Therefore $W^- \supseteq W^{\perp\perp}$.

Comment: Thank you.  The Hilbert projection theorem was what I was missing; I did not know there was a way to do orthogonal projections on infinite dimensional spaces.