# Hilbert space split

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

From the answer in [Prove that, for a closed subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$, $(W^{\perp})^{\perp} = W$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716551/prove-that-for-a-closed-subspace-w-of-a-vector-space-v-w-perp-perp) we have that $W^- = (W^\perp)^\perp.$ How do we show that $V = W^- + W^\perp$?

I have proved this in the case of projections but finding it confusing to write down the solution completely in this case. Can some write down steps of hints?

Answer (score 1):

For any closed subspace $M$ we have $V=M+M^{\perp}$. Take $M=W^{\perp}$. Note that $W^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace for any set $W$.