# Is $(V^\perp)^\perp=\overline{V}$ when $V$ is a subspace of a Hilbert space $H$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Why is $(V^\perp)^\perp=\overline{V}$ when $V$ is a subspace of a Hilbert space $H$? I googled about this but only $V$ as a subspace of finite vector space. Any reference or proof or idea are welcome.

Comment: This is true iff $V$ is a **closed** subspace. Almost any book on FA has a proof.

Comment: It's only true if $V$ is closed.  This is a good exercise to prove for yourself.  If you've already tried, please explain what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited the question. $(V^\perp)^\perp=\overline{V}$ not $(V^\perp)^\perp=V$. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: There could be some weird cases like $V=\emptyset$ but otherwise it is true

Comment: And see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051514/a-subspace-x-is-closed-iff-x-x-perp-perp?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716551/prove-that-for-a-closed-subspace-w-of-a-vector-space-v-w-perp-perp?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989671/if-m-is-a-closed-subspace-of-an-hilbert-space-h-then-m-perp-perp-m?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch the emptyset is not a subspace

Comment: This is true even if $V$ is a dense subset in $\bar{V}$. The density argument relies on the continuity of inner product, as @egreg mentions in his answer in this post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043940/double-orthogonal-complement-is-equal-to-topological-closure).