# $(\mathbf{W}^\perp)^\perp=\mathbf{W}$ where $\mathbf{W}$ is a finite dim'al subspace of an possibly infinite dim'al inner product space $\mathbf{V}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{V}$ be an (not necessarily finite dimensional) inner product space. If $\mathbf{W}$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathbf{V}$, show that $(\mathbf{W}^\perp)^\perp=\mathbf{W}$.

I have shown that $\mathbf{W}\subseteq(\mathbf{W}^\perp)^\perp$ by the fact that $\forall\mathbf{w}\in\mathbf{W}$,$\lt\mathbf{w},\mathbf{w'}\gt=0$ $\forall\mathbf{w'}\in\mathbf{W}^\perp$ but stuck at showing $(\mathbf{W}^\perp)^\perp\subseteq\mathbf{W}$. The condition that $\mathbf{V}$ might be infinite dimensional makes the problem really tricky for me. Can please someone give me a hint?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1716551/42969

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051514/a-subspace-x-is-closed-iff-x-x-perp-perp

Comment: those really helped, thanks!

Comment: A key fact is that $W$ is finite dimensional because this implies that $W$ is closed. It is well known that in this case $(\mathbf{W}^\perp)^\perp=\mathbf{W}$

Answer (score 1):

The comments have pointed out that this is a special case of a more general fact, namely that the result holds whenever $\mathbf{W}$ is a closed subspace.

The general fact is certainly important, but it should be noted that for $\mathbf{W}$ finite dimensional, we don't actually need such topological considerations, even if $\mathbf V$ might be infinite dimensional.

In fact, we can already define a projection onto any finite dimensional space $\mathbf{W}$ by $\pi(v):=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i\rangle e_i\in\mathbf W$, where $e_1,\dots_,e_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbf W$, from which it is immediate to verify that if $v^\perp:=v-\pi(v)$, then $\langle \pi(v),e_i\rangle=0$ for all $i$, whereby $v^\perp\in\mathbf W^\perp$.

(This projection is of course independent of basis, but we don't need that fact for this proof.)

Therefore if $v\in (\mathbf W^\perp)^\perp$, we have
$$\langle v,v\rangle = \langle v,v^\perp+\pi(v)\rangle = \langle v,\pi(v)\rangle = \langle v^\perp+\pi(v), \pi(v)\rangle = \langle \pi(v),\pi(v)\rangle  =\|\pi(v)\|^2.$$

On the other hand, we always have $$\langle v,v\rangle = \langle v^\perp+\pi(v),v^\perp+\pi(v)\rangle = \langle v^\perp,v^\perp\rangle + \langle \pi(v), \pi(v)\rangle =\|v^\perp\|^2+\|\pi(v)\|^2.$$

Therefore $\|v^\perp\|=0$, so $v^\perp=0$ and $v=\pi(v)\in \mathbf W$.