# Hilbert space projection theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

To prove: If for every $f\in H$ ($H$ is a Hilbert space) there is a $p\in V$ such that $\|p−f\|=\min_{v\in V}\|v−f\|$ then $V$ is closed.

I was able to prove the converse of this statement, but not this. I am not able to write down the proof coherently, and [A subspace $X$ is closed iff $X =( X^\perp)^\perp$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051514/a-subspace-x-is-closed-iff-x-x-perp-perp) is confusing me even more! Can someone write down steps of hints to complete this proof?

Answer (score 4):

Well, since a Hilbert space is in particular a metric space, $V$ being closed can be characterized by convergent sequences.

That is, suppose $v_n \in V$ converges to some $f \in H.$  Then we have that there is some $p \in V$ such that
$$\|p-f\| = \min_{v\in V} \|v-f\| \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\|v_n-f\| = 0 \\ \implies f = p \in V$$